# AR(1) - autocorrelation calculation

Tags: self-study, covariance, autoregressive

I am practicing deriving proofs and I cant seem to yield the correct answer for the covariance of an AR(1) model:

$$X_t=pX_{t−1}+e_t.$$

Would greatly appreciate if someone could tell me where I am going wrong:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{Cov}(X_t,X_{t−1}) &= \mathbb{Cov}(pX_{t−1}+e_t,pX_{t−2}+e_{t−1}) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{Cov}(pX_{t−1},pX_{t−2}) + \mathbb{Cov}(pX_{t−1},e_{t−1}) \\ 
&\quad + \mathbb{Cov}(e_t,pX_{t−2})+\mathbb{Cov}(e_t,e_{t−1}) \\[6pt]
&= p^2 \sigma^2.
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Specifically I did $\mathbb{Cov}(pX_{t−1},pX_{t−2}) = p^2 \sigma^2$.  I multiplied the two $p$s together and treated $X_{t-1}$ and $X_{t-2}$ as the variance - but the book says it is just $p \sigma^2$. Can someone tell me why we do not square the $p$?  Many thanks.

Comment: Should you remove common parameter p from the covariance operation?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. If i remove p then my answer would just be sigma^2. But the answer is psigma^2 so I need to leave the p in?

Comment: Ahhh don't worry I have figured it out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Your working is a bit of a mess at the moment.  In your first step you are already replacing $X_t$ with its form at time $t-1$, so presumably it will be easiest to proceed if you keep the other element in that same time index.  Instead, you seem to be making things harder for yourself by also replacing the other element to reduce its time index by one!  If you leave the second element alone (since it is already in the desired time) you get:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{Cov}(X_t, X_{t-1}) 
&= \mathbb{Cov}(pX_{t-1} + e_t, X_{t-1}) \\[6pt]
&= p \cdot \mathbb{Cov}(X_{t-1}, X_{t-1}) + \mathbb{Cov}(e_t, X_{t-1}) \\[6pt]
&= p \cdot \mathbb{V}(X_{t-1}) + 0 \\[6pt]
&= \cdots \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Now, all you need to know is the variance of the AR($1$) process, which can be derived by another method.  (Hint: it is not the same as the variance of the error term.)  That should get you most of the way, and there is not much left to do.